# get date once date is selected from datebox

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, datebox

Right after set method has been passed, I want to know what the date selected is so I can use it in a call to controller

> $('#datetime').bind('datebox', function (e, passed) { 
>          if ( passed.method === 'set' ) {
>         $.load("controller action with the date set");
>                   }
>      });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow, but you want the date that was just set, correct?

From the [Docs](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/events.html):

Trigger to set specified date:

- {'method'} === set
- {'value'} === value to place in input
- {'date'} === the date object being used

So, following your example, passed.value is the * formatted* date, and passed.date is the underlying date object.

Answer (score 2):

never mind i just found it:

```
$('#datetime').bind('datebox', function (e, passed) { if ( passed.method === 'set' ) {alert("The date is now: "+passed.value); } });
```